# JQuery Dialog auto focuses input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a dialog and when I open it by clicking a button the first input field in the dialog's container gets focused. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always manually remove the focus by calling [`blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) on this field.

Or do you need that the field never gets focused?

**EDIT:**

In order to prevent it's focus, you can add `$("firstFieldSelector").focus(function(){return false;}`. It will prevent the focus when opening the dialog. This seems to work at least on ff and chrome: see http://jsfiddle.net/g9GNn/1/ (it uses the jQueryUI example).

Comment: I don't want it to get focused automatically when the dialog box is launched

Answer (score 1):

A great way to battle this issue is to disable all your form inputs:

by Id

```
 $('#inputId').attr("disabled", true);
```

by Class

```
$('.className').attr("disabled",true);
```

by Form

```
$('#formId input').attr("disabled",true);
```

Then on the dialog open call you can re-enable all the elements in the form or individually if that was the path you took.  It doesnt really matter if you disable all of them because you are about to re-enable them all.

```
$("#dialogId").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: X,
                height: Y,
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    **$('#formId input').attr("disabled",false);**
                },
                close: function(){
                    ...
                }
                            ...
            });
```